# Does/can Reachability constantly update internet connectivity status?

Tags: iphone, nsnotificationcenter, reachability, connectivity

There are at least 3 view-controllers in my app where connectivity is necessary. Do I have to start a **new** Reachability test upon entering ***each*** one of those view-controllers (in their viewDidLoad for example), or can I just do it upon launch - like in my AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` - and have it constantly update me from there?

If so, how?

Assume I want to check Reachability from application `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and then again from:
1) imageGalleryViewController
2) latestNewsViewController
3) promotionsViewController

thanks in advance!

Comment: is that the only way? I thought that the Notification Center might be able to update you on status - once/if you register to listen to Reachability events - but I'm not quite sure of this, and if so, how to do it...?

Comment: Hmm. This should work perfectly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a very similar question (and answer) to this which uses `NSNotificationCenter`:

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

Comment: I'm the same person who gave you the comment, I just put it as an answer. And no problem :).